# python child process exit unexpectedly with exit code -9

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pytorch

I have a PyTorch script with 16 processes. Following is a code snippet from the main process:

```
procs = [mp.Process(target=self.worker_wrapper, args=(i, )) for i in range(self.n_workers)]
for p in procs: p.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    for i, p in enumerate(procs):
        self.logger.info('Check: id %d, exitcode %s, alive %s' % (
            i, str(p.exitcode), str(p.is_alive())))
```

the `worker_wrapper` is this:

```
def worker_wrapper(self, id):
    try:
        self.worker(id)
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.info(e)
        self.logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

The `worker` will do some stuff and should never stop. It works well at beginning, but usually after 1 days running, some child processes (not all) exit unexpectedly, I get the output like this:

```
[2017-06-15 08:45:21,540] Check: id 13, exitcode -9, alive False
```

And it didn't catch any exception. I tried to search exitcode -9 but didn't get anything useful. Does anyone meet this before? Or do you have any idea about how to debug this? I'm sorry I can't provide a minimal reproducible code snippet, because it usually takes one day to reproduce. And I'm using python2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exit code -9 means the process was killed via `SIGKILL`.

It's probably due to your machine running out of memory and the OS kernel was triggering the OOM killer.

To verify that, check the kernel logs via `dmesg` you should notice the OOM killer targeting your worker processes.

You need to reduce the memory footprint of your application (or increase the memory of your server/workstation). Also verify your application is not leaking memory.

Comment: Can you link to documentation that -9 means killed by `SIGKILL`?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: Where does it say about exit codes?